# jQuery - Get Content from an XML Page and save to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to get the content of an XML Element into a variable:

```
<ContactPresence>
<ContactUri>test.com</ContactUri>
<PresenceState>offline</PresenceState>
</ContactPresence>
```

How can I get "PresenceState" into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can use [parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
  var xml = "<ContactPresence><ContactUri>test.com</ContactUri<PresenceState>offline</PresenceState></ContactPresence>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $node = $xml.find( "PresenceState" );

  var presenceState = $node.text(); // Should contain offline
```